# If a sequence of functionals converges weakly then it is bounded.

Tags: sequences-and-series, functional-analysis, convergence-divergence, banach-spaces, lp-spaces

Let $f_k, f \in L^{\infty}(R)$ and $f_k \overset * \to f$ in $L^{\infty}(R)$.
Is $f_k$ a bounded sequence in $L^{\infty}(R^n)$?

(Definition: if $(v_n)$ is a sequence in $V = X^*$, we say that $v_n \overset * \to v \in V$ if and only if $\lim \limits _{n \to \infty} v_n x=v x \ \forall x \in X$.)

I guess that if a sequence has a finite limit then the sequence is bounded. But the problem is that it is not an absolute convergence.

Comment: I guess you mean weak* convergent? *Hint:* use the uniform boundedness principle.

Comment: Yes! It is weak* convergent. I defined how I understand it.

Comment: Banach & Steinhaus are your friends...

Comment: @user307459 ok then go for my hint or copper.hat's but we both mean the very same;)

Answer (score 0):

By definition weak* convergence of $f_k$ to $f$ in $X=L^{\infty}(\mathbb R)$ means:

$$lim_{k \to \infty}\langle f^*,f_k\rangle=\langle f^*,f \rangle \space (\forall f^*\in X^*)$$

This is a convergent sequence of reals, hence we have $$sup_{k \in \mathbb N}\Vert \langle f^*,f_k \rangle \Vert = sup_{k \in \mathbb N} \Vert \iota(f_k)(f^*)\Vert < \infty \space (\forall f^* \in X^*)$$
where the $\iota$ denotes the isometric embedding of $X$ into its bidual $X^{**}$. 
Since $\{\iota(f_k)\}_{k \in \mathbb N}$ is a family of bounded linear operator with domain $X^*$ (which is a Banach space!) we can apply Banach-Steinhaus and deduce from the pointwise boundedness the uniform boundedness 
$$sup_{k \in \mathbb N} \Vert \iota(f_k)\Vert < \infty$$

Therefore we obtain by the isometry property:
$$sup_{k \in \mathbb N} \Vert f_k\Vert=sup_{k \in \mathbb N} \Vert \iota( f_k)\Vert < \infty $$
and the claim follows.

Comment: with the $\langle f^*, f \rangle$  I mean the evalutation of $f^*$ at $f$ , not the inner product on $L^{\infty}$.

Comment: write it $f^*(f_k)$, the inner product notation is confusing since we are not in a (pre)Hilbert space (and if $X$ was an Hilbert space  the proof would be much simpler)

Comment: the $ \langle \cdot, \cdot \rangle$ is a very standard notation in functional analysis so I don't see any reason why I should change it. By the context it's very clear what it means.

Comment: ok find somewhere it is used for a Banach space and $f^* \in X^*$, $f \in X$

Comment: http://www2.math.ethz.ch/education/bachelor/lectures/hs2015/math/fa lecture notes page 88 it's even defined using the above notation.

Comment: I'm still saying that's a confusing notation. see https://www.ima.umn.edu/~arnold/502.s97/functional.pdf page 18 it uses mine :-) (and yours 3 lines later !) anyway who cares, just saying I have been confused at first read