# If $X$ is a normed space over $\mathbb{R}$ and $(x_{n})\rightharpoonup x\in X$ then $(x_{n})$ is bounded?

Tags: sequences-and-series, functional-analysis

So if $X$ is a normed space over $\mathbb{R}$ and $(x_{n})$ is a weakly convergent sequence then I want to prove that $(x_{n})$ is bounded.

Since $(x_{n})$ is weakly convergent we have that $f(x_{n})\to f(x)$ for all $f\in X^{\ast}$. Observe that $|f(x_{n})|$ is bounded for all $f\in X^{\ast}$ and we can write $\|x_{n}\|:=\sup\{|f(x_{n})|:\|f\|_{\ast}\le 1\}$. Then applying the Banach-Steinhaus theorem here would yield that $(\|x_{n}\|)\subset\mathbb{R}$ is bounded.

I was wondering if this proof was sufficient?

Comment: Is $X \subset \mathbb R$ a typo ?

Comment: Yes, this is a correct proof in my opinon

Comment: @AndréSchemaitat Yes, sorry.

Comment: @Cornelis Thanks for your feedback!

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1623989/if-a-sequence-of-functionals-converges-weakly-then-it-is-bounded/1643752#1643752 should also answer your question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a consequence of Banach-Steinhaus theorem. Let me state a simpler form of it. Let $Y$ be a normed space over $\mathbb{R}$ and $F$ any family of continuous functionals over $Y$ such that $\sup_{\varphi \in F}|\varphi(y)| < \infty$ for every $y\in Y$. Then $\sup \{|\varphi(y)| \mid \varphi \in F\text{, }\|y\|=1\}<\infty$.

Now let $Y$ be the dual of your space $X$. Every $x_n$ defines a continuous functional $\varphi_n$ on $Y$ by the formula $\varphi_n(y)=y(x_n)$. Since $x_n$ converges weakly, the sequence $\varphi_n(y)$ is bounded for every $y\in Y$. By Banach-Steinhaus, $\sup_{n\text{, }\|y\|=1}|\varphi_n(y)|<\infty$.

To finish the proof, you just need to convince yourself that
$$
\sup_{n\text{, }\|y\|=1}|\varphi_n(y)| = \sup_n\|x_n\|
$$
This comes from the formula for the norm of a functional on $Y$ as a $\sup$ on the unitary sphere and the fact that $\|\varphi_n\| = \|x\|$, which is a consequence of Hahn-Banach theorem.